# Foundation 5 Production Environment Files

Tags: deployment, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower, directory-structure

I've created a new foundation project using the `foundation new myproject --libsass` method.

Its just a simple static index.html (for the purpose of this question).

I've deployed it to a live server now, and I am wondering about the best way to structure this. I have omitted the *node_modules* & *scss* directories, and i'm left with the following:

- bower_components/
- css/
- js/
- index.html
- bowerrc
- bower.json
- Gruntfile.js
- humans.txt
- package.json
- README.md

*bower_components* is needed in its current form, unless I shuffle some files around, which is what I intend to do, but I'm checking if there is a better way of doing this, and that I haven't missed some magic terminal command to deploy to production.

Comment: `magic terminal command to deploy to production` - have you checked out [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)?

Comment: i'm using grunt to watch the SCSS, and to build the initial files. Are you saying its possible to do a deployment too? I'll look into it thanks.

Comment: Grunt is pretty flexible.. depends on where, what and how you're deploying, but there are modules for most eventualities.. here's an example: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [msturdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/658210/msturdy) suggested in the comments, [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) is the way to go here. There are a lot of plugins out there, see a [list](http://gruntjs.com/plugins) on the official page.

If you want to have grunt "compile" your project into one specific folder which you can then for example push to a deployment server, you should do several things in grunt:

1. compile your scss
2. minify your javascript, that is making the files smaller, see [jscompress](http://jscompress.com) for a demo of what it is. All your js-files from /bower_components which you include in your project should be in a vendor.js which is loaded first, and then a second js-file should contain your custom js from /js
3. save everything into a deployment folder.
4. (optional) automatically deploy to a server.

Take a look at these grunt tutorials for setting up your gruntfile.js, you'll want to have two tasks, one for just quickly compiling your scss, one for the whole deployment process:

- [grunt is not weird and hard](http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/)
- [official tutorial](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks)
- [sitepoint tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-awesome-build-script-grunt/)

They show you how to do certain things and definitely how to write the gruntfile. Plugins you might want to use apart from your current libsass plugin are [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and any plugin that lets you deploy your code via [git](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-git), [ftp](https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy) or anything else. You can download all these plugins via npm by adding them to your package.json and doing `npm install`, refer to their websites for exact usage instruction.